# How to save multi-value data into Firebase in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I would like input a lot of hobbies for people who sign up to the my apps. What should I do? Using `UITexField` or the other. There may be a suggestion for input multi value data then save into firebase?

Comment: Could you elaborate?!

Comment: I will input a lot of hobbies but i didn't know UI type which use for input multivalue? after input data will be sent to firebase.

Comment: Well, if I got it right, you might want to use a tableview of cells that contain a textfield

Comment: Yes @AhmadF textfield for input, i will try

Answer (score 0):

From Firebase DB perspective it doesn't matter where the data come from, it's up to you how to collect data from user. It's fine to use `UITextField`, but remember that Firebase DB accepts following types: NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary, NSArray.

And first of all you should read [Firebase guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), there are very well documented.